# Запись на прием на vue js

Tags: vue.js, frontend, backend, vue-cli, client

Нужно сделать на vue js возможность записи на прием к специалисту. То есть у специалиста должно быть свободное время приема, по дням и часам.
Какой принцип создания данной вещи, чем можно воспользоваться, что это вообще - back front?

Comment: ну вопрос очень глобальный и тут нет явного ответа. Поищите в сети данные о том, как создать полноценную систему! Если пробуя ответить на вопрос, то если это ресурс полностью Ваш. то тут нужна, верстка + стили + апи + фронт + бэк + базы данных очень много всего. Если вопрос идёт про сторонние сервисы со специалистами, то нужно искать апи данных ресурсов, подключать или покупать доступ к нему. Далее отправлять запросы с фронта. Если нужно хранить у себя эти данные и еще на почту что-то слать, то возвращаемся обратно к первому пункту который выше

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы создать такой инструмент нужно:

- Прямые руки
- Знания в области PHP/NodeJS/Go/Python для написания бэкенда
- Знания в области Javascript (Angular/Vue/React) для написания фронт части
- Знания в областях HTML и CSS для написания верстки
- Знания в области MySQL для работы и управления Базой Данных

Для начала, Вам нужно разобрать проект на мелкие части (произвести декомпозицию) и написать архитектуру Базы Данных.

После, Вам нужно будет создать UI скелет для того, чтобы пользователь смог "прочесть" навигацию по сайту.
Затем, этот скелет/шаблон нужно сделать интерактивным с помощью JS фреймворков.
И сделать интеграцию с Back-End (серверной) частью, откуда уже будет происходить авторизация и т.д.

И в конечном результате - тестировать свой функционал.

Если вкратце, для такого инструмента, нужно создавать таблицу с врачами/специалистами и создавать ему реляцию со временем, в которое он/она принимает пациента. Также, стоит обратить внимание на промежутки времени между приемами и созданием выходных дней.

Comment: Почему вдруг врачи и пациенты? Может быть автослесари или юристы ;-)

Comment: @Kromster потому-что это то, с чем я работал) Сразу в голову пришло)